# sum of primes and reciprocals of them and plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, primes

Here is two codes in Mathematica to give the sum of primes up to n or up to n-th prime.

```
ps2[n_]:= Sum[If[Element[p,Primes],p,0],{p,2,n}]
```

or

```
ps3[n_]:=Sum[1/Prime[i],{i,1,n}]
```

or

```
ps1[n_]:=Sum[If[Element[p,Primes],p,0],{p,2,n}]
```

or

```
ps[n_]:=Sum[Prime[i],{i,1,n}]
```

Now I am looking for some code to do these sums and plot that in `MATLAB`, any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is rather easy in Matlab:

```
function result = ps(n)
    result = sum(primes(n))
```

(see [PRIMES](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/primes.html))

Answer (score 0):

Using `primes`, as suggested by [@Tobias Kienzler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231555/sum-of-primes-and-reciprocals-of-them-in-matlab/5231636#5231636), you can write the sum of n primes as

```
sumPrimes = sum(primes(n));
```

The sum of the inverse of n primes is

```
sumInversePrimes = sum(1./primes(n));
```

Note that in Matlab, you don't usually write everything as a function; instead you calculate the results and manipulate them as arrays.