# sum the first n prime reciprocals such that the sum exceeds k (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, primes

I am trying to write a program in matlab, such that the sum of the reciprocals of the n first prime numbers exceeds a given value k. To clearify, I am trying to make a function

SumPrime(k)

And it is supposed to return an integer n such that

```
\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1/p_i > k
```

[sum of primes and reciprocals of them and plot in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231555/sum-of-primes-and-reciprocals-of-them-and-plot-in-matlab)

I tried looking here, but this does not quite answer my question. Neither did the command

```
sumInversePrimes = sum(1./primes(n));
```

Here is my attempt. First i define a function for finding the n`th prime number.

```
function Y = NthPrime(n)

if n==1
    Y = 2;
    return
end

if n < 1 || round(n)~=n
    return
end

j = 2;
u = 0;

while u < n

    T = primes(j);
    u = numel(T);
    j = 1 + j;

end

Y = T(numel(T));
```

After doing this (lengthy?) code for finding the n`th prime number, the rest is a cakewalk.

```
function Y = E(u)

sum = 0
n = 0

while sum < u

    n = n + 1

    sum = sum + 1/( NthPrime(n) )

end

Y = n;
```

Return the proper values. This somewhat works. Alas it is very slow, and I guess this is very bad code. I have merely started learning coding in matlab, Could someone please help me either write a better code or optimize mine ?

XOXOXOX

Nebby

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to precompute the sums then find the first that exceeds a threshold:

```
 >> p = primes(1000);
 >> cs = cumsum(1./p);
 >> find(cs > 1.8, 1)
 ans =  25
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work, as I need a much higher amount of primes. I am trying to figure out how many terms I need for the sum to exceed e. Or 2.71828

Comment: It works. You just need a lot of primes:
`find(cumsum(1./primes(120000))>e,1) =  10997`. See http://oeis.org/A046024